# How to pass an array from VBScript to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vbscript

I have a webpage where I am fetching the name of files in a Folder into an array using `VBScript`, then I am passing that array to `JavaScript` variable, so that I can display the names on the screen.

VBScript Code:

```
Function allFiles()
    Dim arr, arr2, oTargetFolder
    arr = array()

    set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    oTargetFolder = "C:\Users\msiddiq1\Documents\WSDLs"

    set objFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(oTargetFolder)

    set oFiles = objFolder.Files

    For Each files in oFiles
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
        arr(UBound(arr)) = files.Name       
    Next

    allFiles = arr
End Function
```

JS:

```
var folderFiles = allFiles();
alert(folderFiles.length); // alerts `undefined`
```

I can pass hardcoded values from vbscript to javascript,  but not this array.

Please suggest.

Comment: Just return a comma separated string instead of array. Split it inside JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wrap the resulting array in a [`VBArray` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y39d47w8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and call [`toArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc634c13(v=vs.94).aspx):

```
var folderFiles = new VBArray(allFiles());
var ff = folderFiles.toArray();
alert(ff.length);
```

or in one line:

```
var folderFiles = (new VBArray(allFiles())).toArray();
```

Note that VBScript is deprecated in IE11 edge mode, so it will be disappearing at some point.